# How to prevent BLUR event from firing multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onblur

I have certain text input fields where if users change a value and then blur away from that text field, the js will fire an ajax request to update that value in the db. The problem is that I wrote a test to get such an event to fire and I notice that the inner 'blur' event usually fires between two and five times after I tab out of the input field:

```
$('input[type=text]').on('input propertychange paste', function() {
    $(this).on('blur', function () {
        console.log('blur');
    });
});
```

Even if I turn off the blur event handler right after catching it, it still fires two or three times. How do I get this to happen only once?

Comment: The reason it is firing multiple times is because you place another copy of the blur handler on the input element every single time you make a change to the value of said element.

Comment: So why do you bind `blur` event inside `'input propertychange paste'` events???

Comment: because I only want to fire the event once the field has been edited and the user has tabbed out of that field. If I just catch the first event, any time I type in a new letter it will fire.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just keep track of a `hasFired` boolean:

```
var hasFired = false;
$('input[type=text]').on('input propertychange paste', function() {
    $(this).on('blur', function () {
        if(!hasFired){
            hasFired = true;
            console.log('blur');
        }
    });
});
```

Actually, the real problem here is that you're binding the `blur` event multiple times. You can use a boolean like above to prevent that:

```
var isBound = false;
$('input[type=text]').on('input propertychange paste', function() {
    if(!isBound){
        isBound = true;
        $(this).on('blur', function () {
            console.log('blur');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This partially works. I can edit a field once and it will fire the blur once. But if I need to re-edit the same field the blur won't occur for obvious reasons. What I can do is set it back to false once the ajax has fired its .done event.

Comment: @Joel: I edited my post, the second option should work better for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be is to create a class for those elements that already bound by that event.

```
$('input[type=text]').on('input propertychange paste', function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass("bound")) {
      $(this).on('blur', function () {
         $(this).addClass("bound");
         console.log('blur');
      });
    }
});
```